# Producing a smooth curve from numerical minimization

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, mathematical-optimization

I have a function f(pA, pB, pAB, x) where pA,pB and pAB depend on x.

```
f[pA, pB, pAB, x] = -(x pA/(2 lA)) Log[(8 x)/(lA E)] - ((1 - x) pB/(2 lB)) Log[8 (1 - x)/(lB E)] - (x pAB/ lA) Log[8(1 - x)/(lB E)] + (x/(2 lA)) (pA Log[pA] + 2 pAB Log[AB] + 2 (1 - pA - pAB) Log[1 - pA - pAB]) + ((1 - x)/(2 lB)) (pB Log[pB] + 2(1 - pB - ((lB x)/(lA (1 - x))) pAB) Log[(1 - pB - ((lB x)/(lA (1 - x))) pAB)]) - (epsilonA x pA)/(2 lA) - (epsilonB (1 - x) pB)/(2 lB) - (epsilonAB x pAB)/lA
```

pA,pB and pAB are found by minimizing f at each x with respect to pA,pB and pAB.

However, there are constraints such as pA<1, pB<1, pAB<1, pA+pAB<1 and pB+pAB*x/(1-x)<=1.

lA, lB, epsilonA, epsilonB, epsilonAB are constants.

My goal is to plot f as a function of x in the range (0,1).

I used **FindMinimum** to minimize f with respect to pA,pB and pAB at each x (in a loop) and then plug the solution (pA, pB and pAB) into f to get its value. However, this leads to curves with kinks. This is the last thing I would like to see. I used **PrecisionGoal, SetPrecision**, but to no avail.The file is attached here. I would also like to bring to your notice that when I perform constrained minimization using **FindMinimum** does not obey the constraints while exploring the search space, (hence resulting in errors such as the function is not real for ..). This caused me to resort to using a **piecewise function**, where I use the limiting values of the function at the boundary such as for pA+pAB<1, etc.. The code is attached below if you would like to copy it and test it. Note that in the code, phiAloc is the same as x that I defined in f [pA,pB,pAB,x].

```
lA = 500;
lB = 500;

NA = 5000;
NB = 5000;
phiAlist = Range[0.01, 0.99, 0.01];
totalpoints = Length[phiAlist];
chi = 0.0004;
epsilonA = 0.0;
epsilonB = 0.0;
epsilonAB = 0.0;
funcfint[pA_, pB_, pAB_, 
phiAloc_] := (Piecewise[{{-(phiAloc*pA/(2*lA))*
   Log[(8*phiAloc)/(lA*E)] - ((1 - phiAloc)*pB/(2*lB))*
   Log[8*(1 - phiAloc)/(lB*E)] - (phiAloc*pAB/lA)*
   Log[8*(1 - phiAloc)/(lB*E)] + (phiAloc/(2*lA))*(pA*Log[pA] + 
     2 pAB*Log[pAB] + 
     2*(1 - pA - pAB)*
      Log[1 - pA - pAB]) + ((1 - phiAloc)/(2*lB))*(pB*Log[pB] + 
     2*(1 - pB - ((lB*phiAloc)/(lA*(1 - phiAloc)))*pAB)*
      Log[(1 - 
         pB - ((lB*phiAloc)/(lA*(1 - phiAloc)))*
          pAB)]) - (epsilonA*phiAloc*pA)/(2*
     lA) - (epsilonB*(1 - phiAloc)*pB)/(2*lB) - (epsilonAB*
     phiAloc*pAB)/lA, 
 pA + pAB < 1 && 
  pB + pAB*(lB * phiAloc)/(lA*(1 - phiAloc)) < 
   1}, { -(phiAloc*pA/(2*lA))*
   Log[(8*phiAloc)/(lA*E)] - ((1 - phiAloc)*pB/(2*lB))*
   Log[8*(1 - phiAloc)/(lB*E)] - (phiAloc*pAB/lA)*
   Log[8*(1 - phiAloc)/(lB*E)] + (phiAloc/(2*lA))*(pA*Log[pA] + 
     2 pAB*Log[pAB] + 0) + ((1 - phiAloc)/(2*lB))*(pB*Log[pB] + 
     2*(1 - pB - ((lB*phiAloc)/(lA*(1 - phiAloc)))*pAB)*
      Log[(1 - 
         pB - ((lB*phiAloc)/(lA*(1 - phiAloc)))*
          pAB)]) - (epsilonA*phiAloc*pA)/(2*
     lA) - (epsilonB*(1 - phiAloc)*pB)/(2*lB) - (epsilonAB*
     phiAloc*pAB)/lA, 
 pA + pAB >= 
   1 && (pB + pAB*(lB * phiAloc)/(lA*(1 - phiAloc)) < 
    1)}, { -(phiAloc*pA/(2*lA))*
   Log[(8*phiAloc)/(lA*E)] - ((1 - phiAloc)*pB/(2*lB))*
   Log[8*(1 - phiAloc)/(lB*E)] - (phiAloc*pAB/lA)*
   Log[8*(1 - phiAloc)/(lB*E)] + (phiAloc/(2*lA))*(pA*Log[pA] + 
     2 pAB*Log[pAB] + 
     2*(1 - pA - pAB)*
      Log[1 - pA - pAB]) + ((1 - phiAloc)/(2*lB))*(pB*Log[pB] + 
     0) - (epsilonA*phiAloc*pA)/(2*lA) - (epsilonB*(1 - phiAloc)*
     pB)/(2*lB) - (epsilonAB*phiAloc*pAB)/lA, 
 pA + pAB < 1 && 
  pB + pAB*(lB * phiAloc)/(lA*(1 - phiAloc)) >= 
   1}, { -(phiAloc*pA/(2*lA))*
   Log[(8*phiAloc)/(lA*E)] - ((1 - phiAloc)*pB/(2*lB))*
   Log[8*(1 - phiAloc)/(lB*E)] - (phiAloc*pAB/lA)*
   Log[
    8*(1 - phiAloc)/(lB*E)] + (phiAloc/(2*lA))*(pA*Log[pA] + 
     2 pAB*Log[pAB] + 0) + ((1 - phiAloc)/(2*lB))*(pB*Log[pB] + 
     0) - (epsilonA*phiAloc*pA)/(2*lA) - (epsilonB*(1 - phiAloc)*
     pB)/(2*lB) - (epsilonAB*phiAloc*pAB)/lA, 
 pA + pAB >= 1 && 
  pB + pAB*(lB * phiAloc)/(lA*(1 - phiAloc)) >= 1}}])
finterlist = {};
composition = {};
pABlist = {};
pAlist = {};
pBlist = {};
sumlist = {};
Do[ phiAloc = phiAlist[[i]]; 
  g = FindMinimum[{funcfint[u, v, w, phiAloc], 
 0 < u <= 1 && 0 < v <= 1 && 0 < w <= 1 && u + w <= 1 && 
  v + (lB*phiAloc/(lA*(1 - phiAloc)))*w <= 1}, {u, v, w}] ;
  prob = {u, v, w} /. g[[2]];
  pA = prob[[1]];
  pB = prob[[2]];
  pAB = prob[[3]];
  sum = pB + (phiAloc/(1 - phiAloc))*
 pAB;(*just checking whether the constraint is satisfied*)

  finter = funcfint[pA, pB, pAB, phiAloc];
  (* free=funcfenergy[pA,pB,pAB,phiAloc];*)

  AppendTo[composition, phiAloc]; AppendTo[pAlist, pA]; 
  AppendTo[pBlist, pB]; AppendTo[pABlist, pAB]; 
  AppendTo[finterlist, finter];
  AppendTo[sumlist, sum],
  {i, 1, totalpoints, 1}];
finterplot = Transpose[{composition, finterlist}];
finterfunction = Interpolation[finterplot, Method -> "Spline"];
pAplot = Transpose[{composition, pAlist}];
pBplot = Transpose[{composition, pBlist}];
pABplot = Transpose[{composition, pABlist}];
sumplot = Transpose[{composition, sumlist}];
Plot[finterfunction[x], {x, 0.01, 0.99}]
Plot[finterfunction'[x], {x, 0.01, 0.99}]
ListPlot[pAplot]
ListPlot[pBplot]
ListPlot[pABplot]
ListPlot[sumplot]
```

Comment: It is not likely that you will receive many responses with such a long block of code.  Can you illustrate your issue with a shorter example?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1146934

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved on http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1146934 by setting `WorkingPrecision -> 30` and setting the precision of the parameters to `30`, too.